# html Element has no height

Tags: html, css

My element has no height, but it's filled with images now the Anchor around the images is not clickable unless i give .portfolio a fixed height.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

THE HTML :

```
    <h1 class="text-center">
        Een greep uit ons portfolio
    </h1>
    <span class="main-underline"></span>

    <div class="portfolio">
        <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="portfolio-img">
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio',array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
```

THE CSS:

```
/*PORTFOLIO*/

#main2 {

}

.portfolio {

}

.portfolio .portfolio-img img{
    width:100%;
}

.portfolio .col-md-3 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

The result:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's called "clearing" elements. You probably just need to add the class `row` beside `portfolio`

Comment: Please post a sample of output html, instead of php code

Comment: @judgeja: Please post your solution as an [answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) rather than a [comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). This will allow the OP to [accept](//stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) your answer, and will make it easier for other users to find and [vote](//stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) on answers.

Comment: @ScottWeldon I would have but the example code given wasn't enough to easily throw together a replication in jsfiddle with my suggestion implemented, and I didn't want to post an answer that I wasn't sure would help...

Comment: @judgeja you we're right. When i put the row around it ir worked. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Set `display` of `a` to `inline-block`.